# How to to set default file format with spark-submit command

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I want to use a default format that is not `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe` (currently, the default format used by Spark when I try to create a table).
Specifically, I am looking for a CLI configuration to not hardcode the format in the Spark code, an homologous to `spark-sql --hiveconf hive.default.fileformat=<format>` configuration but for the spark-submit command.

The closest configuration I have found for spark-submit is [Custom Configurations for Hive and Hadoop](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/configuration.html#custom-hadoophive-configuration), but these does not work, the result is the same.

Custom Configuration example:

```
spark-submit script.py \
     --conf spark.hive.default.fileformat=Parquet \
     --conf spark.hive.default.fileformat.managed=Parquet \
```

I know there are multiple ways to set the format using Spark Conf or Spark-sql '`STORE AS`', but that is not what I need, as these are configurations made IN the file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If still relevant, I was playing around that area myself and found something.

You can change the default `provider` not to be Hive and then change the default source. Both are spark "regular" properties, so maybe they will work from the command line:

```
spark.sql.legacy.createHiveTableByDefault=false
spark.sql.sources.default=parquet  # this is the default anyways
```